# Using boost asio stream_handle with sequential like file based devices

Tags: c++, windows, boost-asio

I am considering using asio to perform "overlapped" (completion ports) style IO on a windows "device handle" created with CreateFile(...overlapped...)

I have quite a particular design though, because of specifics of my application I must maintain a different thread pool for performing the actual processing of data(work pool) and a pool (a very small one, could be just one thread maybe) of actual IO completions triggered by the processing pool.

Basically, at the beginning I want to trigger a handful of IO requests to my device that are initiated from IO pool. When these complete I notify a scheduling component that *POSTS* the completion packets content to different threads in the work pool. These completion notifications return quickly because actual processing will happen in work pool -> and from a particular work pool thread after processing takes place a new "read" is initiated that should trigger completion on the io pool.

Is this dissociation possible using windows::stream_handle ? In general seems the asio API associates read completions with the same io_service associated with the stream object.

**EDIT**
Been a long time now, as I've already implemented the approach.
I've updated my response to reflect my choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I create the "device" handle using windows specific function:

   HANDLE file_handle = CreateFile(... FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED ...);
2. I can associate/register the handle with my ioService so that all overlapped requests to the device are handled by one of the ioService thread(s).

   error_code ec;
     auto &io_service_impl = use_service(ioservice);
     io_service_impl.register_handle(file_handle, ec);
3. Then I can use the asio overlapped to initiate async IO from a different thread than ioService.run(), making it trigger completion in the io service thread(s):

   ```
       void IoPool::InitiateNewRead()
       {

       service.post([this]() {auto handler = InterceptorReadHandler::Create(bufferPool, data, service);
                   handler->SetContext(context);

                   return device.Read(std::move(handler));
               });
           }
       }
   ```
4. For reference a device read implementation:

   ```
   bool Device::Read(std::shared_ptr<InterceptorReadHandler> handler) {
   auto handlerWrapper = [handler](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t len) {
       handler->Completion(ec, len);
   };
   win::overlapped_ptr overlapped(handler->GetService(), handlerWrapper);


   unsigned long bytesRead = 0;
   auto& packet = handler->GetBuffer();
   auto ok = ::ReadFile(handle,
                        packet.data,
                        static_cast<DWORD> (packet.length),
                        &bytesRead,
                        overlapped.get()) ? true : false;

   auto lastError = ::GetLastError();
   if (!ok && lastError != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
       boost::system::error_code errCode(lastError, boost::system::get_system_category());
       overlapped.complete(errCode, 0);
       return false;
   } else {
       overlapped.release();
   }

   return true;
   ```

   }